# Looking for a Sutta wherein the Buddha talks about dreams

Tags: pali-canon, the-buddha, texts, dreams

In the Dhamma talk [*"Sleeping and dreaming"*](https://www.arrowriver.ca/desana.html), by Ajahn Punnadhammo, he mentions that in the Anguttara Nikaya (no specific sutta mentioned) the Buddha talked about the origins of dreams and different kinds of dreams.

He taught that some dreams could be visions of the past and future, messages from Devas and "Wind in the belly" meaning random content with no real significance.

What sutta is this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/30508/254) said that's in the Milinda Pañha.

> Source: milindapañha, anumānapañho, vessantaravaggo, supinapañho

Comment: That is the right answer (by Ven. Yuttadhammo). Thanks @ChrisW.

Comment: The OP asked about the Anguttara Nikaya. The Milinda Pañha is in the KN and is probably not a "sutta".

Comment: @Dhammadhatu True enough. And a common reason for not finding something is looking for it in the wrong place. :-)

Answer (score 0):

"When the Tathagata — worthy & rightly self-awakened — was still just an unawakened bodhisatta, five great dreams appeared to him. Which five?"

[AN 5.196](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.196.than.html)